# Matrix multiplication using sym function error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

When multiplied `A = eye(3,3)` with `x = sym('x',[3,3])` as in this form `(A.*x)`,  I got a result. But when multiply `A = eye(3,3)` with `y = sym('y',[3,2])` I got an error while from the matrix multiplication point of view it is correct. Why it is so?

Answer (score 1):

`.*` is not matrix multiplication, it is element-wise multiplication. You want to do `A*x`.